# How to fix Checkstyle empty block warning

Tags: java, checkstyle, suppress-warnings

I wanted to know the proper way of resolving this issue with a Checkstyle report where it points out an empty else block: "Must have at least one statement". We do not log anything in those classes and I think printing anything on console is also not a good idea. What would be the best way to handle this?

[image: code example with empty "else if" block]

Comment: Your checkstyle configuration probably points this out for a good reason. Why do you need that empty else-block? For catching with try/catch it would be necessary but for if/else not. Why not just leave the empty block away?

Comment: Really, I think the best would be to not trick Checkstyle by using an empty statement like `;` or other fake statements but rather ask yourself why you need this and why you do not change the code. Or else, if the checkstyle configuration should be less strict.

Comment: I think there are legitimate cases where this makes sense from a code readability standpoint -- you are saying to maintainers "Yes, I thought of this case, there's nothing that needs to be done here." It shouldn't be an issue performance-wise, because any reasonable compiler should eliminate that branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just add `;` between that braces

```
.
.
.
else if(condition){
    ;
}
.
.
.
```

or as @Fred Larson said you can just insert a comment if you have any comment that why this section is empty

```
.
.
.
else if(condition){
    //the reason why this section is empty
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Really, would that take care of this issue. I need to run the report.

Comment: Even a comment might do it. A comment would be good to explain why you have an empty `else if` block anyway.

Comment: While later may be good practice it will not solve the problem of OP as he clearly states that the task is to prevent his Checkstyle from marking this as problem. A comment will not clear the Checkstyle problem, the code of OP already has a comment `//Do nothing` there.

Comment: Comment is not resolving my issue but semi colon did.

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress the warning within a class or block of code by using `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:EmptyBlock")` if you have the [`SuppressWarningsFilter`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressWarningsFilter) Checkstyle filter configured.

#### YourClass.java

```java
public class YourClass {

  @SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:EmptyBlock")
  public void yourMethod() {
    if (someBoolean()) {
      doSomething();
    } else {
      // Do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

#### checkstyle.xml

```xml
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="SuppressWarningsFilter" />
  ...

  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder" />
    ...
  </module>
</module>
```

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:emptyblock")` worked for me